# Combine shell boolean conditions with selective precedence

Tags: shell

I have two conditions at the beginning of a script to verify arguments. The intention is that exactly two arguments should be passed and the first argument must be `"FOO"` or `"BAR"`. What I have below works, but I want to know how to make this a single if statement:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 <FOO or BAR> <Removed for SO>"
        exit
fi
if [ "$1" != "FOO " -a "$1" != "BAR" ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 <FOO or BAR> <Removed for SO>"
        exit
fi
```

Just to clarify, what I am asking is how in general to combine "logical and" with "logical or" in a shell script. In pseudo code this is what I would want:

```
if ( numArgs != 2 || (someArg != "FOO" && someArg  != "BAR") )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `||` between 2 conditions:

```
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ] || [ "$1" != "FOO" -a "$1" != "BAR" ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 <FOO or BAR> <Removed for SO>"
        exit
fi
```

Comment: Does `-a` in the condition on the right have a higher precedence than `||`?

Comment: Precedence is not needed since everything after `||` is in `[ ... ]` which means `[ ... ]` will be evaluated separately.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expression matching:

```
if [[ $# != 2 && ! $1 =~ ^(FOO|BAR)$ ]]
then
   ...
fi
```

This has the advantage that it easier to adapt, if more values should be allowed for the first parameter.

I would, however, **not** combine both conditions into one, but leave them separately and provide different error messages for both.